# kapacitor: setting slack webhook URL in .tick file

Tags: docker, slack, kapacitor

I am using a TICK stack deployed in Docker containers. I would like to set up kapacitor alerts to send different notifications based on alert levels (ie. crit, warn, inform). As far as I can see, the only way to do this is by using different alert nodes, one for each alert type. I am using SLACK as one of my alert types but would like to send to different slack web hooks, again, based on the alert level.  Configuring the kapacitor.conf file as such:

```
[slack]
  # Configure Slack.
  enabled = true
  # The Slack webhook URL, can be obtained by adding     
  # an Incoming Webhook integration.
  # Visit https://slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook
  # to add new webhook for Kapacitor.
  url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/....."
```

Makes is so that all alert notes that send to slack, send the alert to that webhook. Is there a way to configure the alert node to send to a specific webhook dynamically from within the .tick file. For example:

```
stream
  |from()
    .measurement('cpu')
  |alert()
    .slack()
    .warn(lambda: "usage_user" > 50)           
      .url("https://hooks.slack.com/services/some_url")
    .crit(lambda: "usage_user" > 70) 
      .url("https://hooks.slack.com/services/another_url")
```

I see that other alert types allow for configuration from the .tick file but I have not been able to find much in the Slack alert. Thanks.

Comment: Is the information in the [kapacitor alert node for slack](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.1/nodes/alert_node/#slack) not sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to make it more clear. I want to be able to send to a specific web hook depending on the level. In the documentation, you have to set the web hook in the conf file so ALL slack notifications get sent to the same webhook

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think that it's currently possible, I'd encourage you to open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/new) for this in Kapacitor.